# npm warning to install the firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

When I installing the firebase with 'npm install -g firebase' to my react-native project. I received this warning message

```
npm WARN @grpc/grpc-js@1.1.0 requires a peer of google-auth-library@5.x || 6.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

[image]

How I solve this warning?

Comment: this is not error, it is only warning.

Comment: you should consider using `@react-native-firebase` instead of the `firebase` SDK.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
npm i firebase
npm install google-auth-library -g
```

then

```
npm install firebaseui --save
```

then all the missing bits and warning have gone.